# Making a cURL API call with R

Tags: r, curl

I am trying to make a cURL API call with R and I am unable to retrieve data. Or more specifically I am unable to figure out how to translate a multi-line curl call into an R command.

I am trying to get data from Twitch, the Twitch Developers API page offers the following curl code. Though I am unsure about the syntax of the call.

```
curl -H 'Accept: application/vnd.twitchtv.v5+json' \
-H 'Client-ID: uo6dggojyb8d6soh92zknwmi5ej1q2' \
-X GET 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/games/top'
```

I have attempted variations of:

```
library(curl)
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

df <- GET('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/games/top', add_headers('Accept: application/vnd.twitchtv.v5+json', 'Client-ID: uo6dggojyb8d6soh92zknwmi5ej1q2'))
fromJSON(df)

df <- curl_download('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/games/top', destfile = 'C:\\....\\curldta.csv')
fromJSON(df)
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: if you look at `rawToChar(df$content)` from your first query, you'll see the error message "No client id specified". Something to track down...

Comment: And if you change your `add_headers` to `add_headers(c(Accept ='application/vnd.twitchtv.v5+json', `Client-ID` `= 'uo6dggojyb8d6soh92zknwmi5ej1q2'))`  (named vector, where the Client-ID is surrounded by back-ticks), you get the error: "Invlaid client id"

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a [package](https://github.com/Freguglia/rTwitchAPI) that is a wrapper of twitch API for R language (you can install packages from github it with devtools package). The data frame you're trying to get can be obtained with

```
library(rTwitchAPI)
twitch_auth("YOUR_CLIENT_ID")
df = get_top_games()$data
```